# keep 2 chart.js contained in a div

Tags: css, html, chart.js, chart.js2

So I am trying to contain 2 chart.js in a main div with position:relative. somehow, if I don't set the `vw` or the `vh` correctly, they will be outside the container. is there anyway to prevent this?

here is the code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('example1').getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["some", "thing", "came", "up", "today"],
    "datasets": [{
      "label": "abs_base_notional",
      "data": [10.106688, 24.342801, 25.908431, 98.147767, 94.194484],
      "backgroundColor": ["#4f5643", "#DAA276", "#6a7587", "#5FA4EC", "#8CB277"],
      "borderColor": ["#4f5643", "#DAA276", "#6a7587", "#5FA4EC", "#8CB277"]
    }]
  },
  "options": {
    "title": {
      "text": "test in (M$)",
      "display": true
    },
    "legend": {
      "display": false
    },
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [],
      "yAxes": []
    }
  }
})

var ctx = document.getElementById('example2').getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["some", "thing", "came", "up", "today"],
    "datasets": [{
      "label": "base_notional",
      "data": [-4.95651, 13.800001, -0.404782, 98.147767, -2.787737],
      "backgroundColor": ["#4f5643", "#DAA276", "#6a7587", "#5FA4EC", "#8CB277"],
      "borderColor": ["#4f5643", "#DAA276", "#6a7587", "#5FA4EC", "#8CB277"]
    }]
  },
  "options": {
    "title": {
      "text": "second test (M$)",
      "display": true
    },
    "legend": {
      "display": false
    },
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [],
      "yAxes": []
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-size: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.chart-container-double {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 40vw;
  border-size: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="chart-container-double">
    <canvas id="example1"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="chart-container-double">
    <canvas id="example2"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I am quite new to html/css/js so I see that there is errors but I don't know how to fix them. any help would be appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should learn about flex-box. The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without having to use floats or positioning.

you can start here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Another option is to use Bootstrap.

Bootstrap includes a powerful mobile-first flexbox grid system for building layouts of all shapes and sizes. It’s based on a 12 column layout and has multiple tiers, one for each media query range. You can use it with Sass mixins or our predefined classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/

hope this helps